# In the review pages the question text bleeds through the action box on top

Tags: bug, review, design

When using the review functionality and I scroll down, the Answer text is hidden by the information box but buttons and tags are visible. The question however completely shines through. See screenshot below.
The Answer is above the "Vote up or down to rate the answers helpfulness" and the question is below.

[image: Question and up-down arrows bleeding through info box]

Comment: @Glorfindel It looks like the same issue.